# GWT Widget that grow

Tags: gwt, panel, widget

I need to create a GWT Custom Widget. This widget will contain a panel and that widget must grow in height based on the amount of text in the panel

Edit:

for e.g. let's say a widget will hold a forum post. What happens is that there is a panel inside the widget that hold the forum post. The more text text, the greater the panel??

Any idea??

Comment: is this not happening by default? what container are you using now?

Comment: If i use a label to hold the text inside an absolute panel, would it be OK??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a `Label` in a `FlowPanel`, the whole thing will size itself to contain whatever text you put in the `Label`.  Most GWT widgets will do that as long as you don't set an explicit size.

Once you start setting the size (e.g. "height: 100px") yourself, then you have to start re-calculating the size yourself.  So... don't set the size yourself! :)

Comment: but, can a label continue as next line

Comment: Yes. A `Label` basically boils down to a `<div>`, so its behavior is just like a `<div>`.  You can set different styles on it to affect that behavior (just like a `<div>`).